# Fetching data from arrays in payload using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave

```
**Input**
{
 "result": [
            [
              {
                "ID": "12345",
                "Name": "xyz",
              },
              {
                "ID": "12345",
                "Title": "abc",
               }
            ]
          ]
"result": [
            [
              {
                "ID": "67890",
                "Name": "pqr",
              }
            ]
          ]
          }
```

**Output**

Trying to fetch data from arrays in payload. output data should be in xml format
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is expected output: 
    **Output**
    <result>
       <root>
          <ID>12345</ID>
          <Name>xyz</Name>
       </root>
       <root>
          <ID>12345</ID>
          <Name>abc</Name>
       <root>
    </result>
    <result>
       <root>
          <ID>67890</ID>
          <Name>pqr</Name>
       </root>
    </result>

Comment: Please edit the question and add the expected result there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit convoluted because of the level of nesting. I needed an additional reduce() at the end to convert from an array to objects.
I also needed to edit the input because it is not a valid JSON.

Input:

```json
{
    "result": [
            [
              {
                "ID": "12345",
                "Name": "xyz"
              },
              {
                "ID": "12345",
                "Title": "abc"
               }
            ]
          ],
    "result": [
            [
              {
                "ID": "67890",
                "Name": "pqr"
              }
            ]
          ]
}
```

Script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    result: 
        payload.*result flatMap 
            $ flatMap 
                $ flatMap ((item, index) -> 
                    { 
                        root: { 
                            ID: item.ID, 
                            Name: item.Name default item.Title
                        } 
                    }
                ) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> accumulator ++ item)    
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<result>
  <root>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
  </root>
  <root>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </root>
  <root>
    <ID>67890</ID>
    <Name>pqr</Name>
  </root>
</result>
```

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<result>
  <root>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
  </root>
  <root>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </root>
</result>
<result>
  <root>
    <ID>67890</ID>
    <Name>pqr</Name>
  </root>
</result>

Comment: For second result in json, there should <result><root>
    <ID>67890</ID>
    <Name>pqr</Name>
  </root>
</result>

Comment: sorry for the formatting, I am unable to get it in proper way

Comment: If I understand correctly you want an XML with two top elements. That is not valid in XML. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes @aled. For two arrays (Result) in input payload, I want separate top elements as <Result> </Result> for each array.

Comment: Are you aware that having two top elements is not valid in the XML standard? Do you instead want this result as an intermediate step for some other change later?

Comment: As Aled had said that wouldn't be valid XML and as such isn't supported by the XML parser; why would DataWeave support creating invalid output? You should instead consider something like `<Results><Result>...</Result><Result>...</Result></Results>` If you absolutely have to have it that way you're going to have to manually build the final output as text.

Comment: Thanks aled and Michael for letting me know this. I am new to mulesoft and dataweave. one of my requirements was like this. I tried and could not get it. thats why posted here

Comment: It is possible to do that with sting manipulation but usually that is a bad practice and should be avoided. See this answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524796/721855